# How to determine whether an IP adress is static or dynamic without root rights

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, suse

On SUSE linux, I want to determine whether the IP address of the machine is assigned statically or dynamically without having root access to machine. What commands can I use for this purpose? What files can I read to get at this information?

Comment: What is the difference between a static and a dynamic address? You can "statically" assing by hand the same address `dhclient` is assigning *dynamically* to an interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference. You can have DHCP assign a "borrowed" IP address (i.e., it can get assigned to something else if not in use), or have it assign always the same address. You can set the address by hand, and change it at will. You can configure the system so that it assigns the same address on boot.

The only important datum is the current address, how it got there is moot.

Comment: I won't go so far as saying *The only important datum is the current address, how it got there is moot.* because changing the address on reboot can change the system's behaviour, e.g., as a client in a backup system. But your point is definitely valid.